# Intersection of a divisor with a principal divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am new in the study of surfaces in the algebraic geometry point of view. I am studying chapter V of Hartshorne. At some point while studying I came accross with the following thought which I was wondering if its true since I can neither prove nor disprove it. Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface.  I've read that the bilinear pairing $DivX\times DivX\to \mathbb{Z}$ respects linear equivalence and hence gives a symmetric bilinear map $Pic X\times Pic X\to \mathbb{Z}$. Does that in particular imply that for any divisor D and
any principal divisor $(f)$ we have that $D\cdot (f)=0$. Does the last statement hold in general ? If so could I get some proof ?

Comment: The image of a principal divisor in $\operatorname{Pic} X$ is the identity element, which corresponds to the empty divisor. Obviously intersecting anything with the empty divisor results in an empty intersection hence vanishing intersection number.

Comment: @TabesBridges Hmm, but what is the empty divisor? The empty set is not irreducible and hence, not a prime divisor.

Comment: How is the empty set not irreducible? The only way to write it as a union of two closed sets is $\emptyset \cup \emptyset$, no?

Comment: @TabesBridges No, because $\emptyset=\text{Spec}0$ where $0$ denotes the zero( or trivial) ring. This ring is not a domain hence $\emptyset$ cannot be irreducible.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Perhaps you can nevertheless argue that empty intersection implies $0$ intersection number based on the properties that Hartshorne proves? This can't be *that* hard...

Comment: @TabesBridges typically nonemptiness is included in the definition of irreducibility, cf [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004V), for instance. You are of course correct that the intersection of anything with the empty divisor has vanishing intersection number because the intersection is empty. If the OP is interested in a proof, they should include their definitions: there should be some sort of sum over things indexed by elements of the intersection, and then everything falls in to place because the empty sum is zero.

Comment: @TabesBridges Essentially, what I am wondering about is that "how can prove that if $D$ is a divisor and $f$ a rational function then $D\cap V(f)=\emptyset$". Here $V(f)$ is the support of the divisor $(f)$. I already know that trivial intersection implies $0$ intersection number.

Comment: You mean without appealing to linear equivalence? Because what you have written in the last comment is not precisely true: choose a non-constant rational function $f$, write $\operatorname{div}(f) = \sum_{i=1}^k m_i p_i$, and now let $D = p_1$. Then $D \cap V(f) = \left\{p_1\right\}$. You really do need to pass to some equivalence relation.